# PHP file() - Failed to Open Stream: Connection timed out

Tags: php

I'm having a problem troubleshooting this issue about "failed to open stream: connection timed out". There is this application deployed in a server (ip.server.of.main.app). In some part of its code, it is posting data using this code:

$f = file('ip.server.of.another.app/tracker.php?var1=value1&var2=value2')

This **ip.server.of.another.ap/tracker.php?var1=value1&var2=value2** is posting the data of the variables passed on the script.

But this line always timed out. In my local pc, when I run a test code containing that line, it didn't timed out and successfully posted the data on the database.

Is there any possible cause why it only timed out when run on the server of the main app?

Comment: Try this: file_get_contents(ip.server.of.another.app/tracker.php?var1=value1&var2=value2, false);

Comment: Different servers behave differently. That's just how it is. What you can do is pass a [stream_context](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) to the call (as a third option on your [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file) call) with a bit longer timeout setting. I don't know the syntax by hand, but google something like "php stream context timeout" or similar and you should be able to find something.

Comment: Time out may be set in many places with various condition. In my trainee place I set time out very short - in a case of never-ending stories. To each script I include this timer(). Someone set it for to short and maybe even forgot clean it up, or your access is not welcome :)